# how to disable the draggabe div?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a five draggable div A,B,C,D,E.

When I drag a A Div and drop the desired droppable position,other draggable div is disabled.I wrote the disable code. Its work for other draggable div except E draggable div

```
Demo
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awyphvyv/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because jquery remember your last droppable definition, and it don't include your "e" element disabling

here is a fixed solution :

```
$(".draggable").draggable('disable');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awyphvyv/26/

note :  never use the same id twice  (you have many "first" id)

note 2 : you should write an unique function called when the dropable event is fired